Sanitize Query String to Avoid XSS
My (legacy) site is built with Kentico v12 Portal Engine.
I have [1] a custom Page Type to hold a list of people, including their "Initial", and [2] a page to display each person's data based on the querystring value of the person's initial.
For example if the page URL is www.example.com/sales?i=jd, then Jane Doe's info is displayed.
On the page there's a Repeater webpart to point at the custom Page Type with a WHERE condition like this: Initial = '{% QueryString.i #%}'
Now everything is working fine. However, the IT team has asked me to fix the XSS vulnerabilities of the page above.
I guess I'd need to sanitize the querystring value (i), however, I've tried different things including editing the WHERE condition to this Initial = '{% UrlEncode(QueryString.i) #%}', but nothing worked.
Please help, let me know how to properly sanitize the querystring and fix the XSS vulnerabilities.

I would recommend checking the documentation on XSS and use e.g. QueryHelper.GetText() method in the macro. Or, macros with parameters like 'encode' and 'handlesqlinjection' - {% QueryString.Param|(handlesqlinjection)true %}  {% QueryString.Param|(encode)true %}
(docs)

Thank you! The XSS document was the first one that I've checked. In this case, it was my mistake that the XSS was not fixed. I've missed a spot where I've used ?i= without sanitizing it. As usual, thanks for you input!
